# How do you resolve Visual Studio (Xamarin) Error NETStandard 2.0 incompatibility issues?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

Developer created a project and pushed to GitHub. I downloaded it but I can't compile it. We looked at each others IDE and can't see a difference.

I created a blank project and tried to add one of the packages -> Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision but I get an error because of NETStandard 2.0.

[image: NETStandard 2.0 Errors]

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: You need to update your packages to their latest version and hope they have the support of  .NetStandard 2.1

Comment: What target framework is your application using? To link to a library that's built for .netstandard2.1, you need to target .NET 5.0 or above.

Comment: The target frameworks I have the ability to choose are from 1.0 -> 2.1. I cannot choose anything higher.

Comment: Here is the FULL Error

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error NU1202 Package System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.3.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.3.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)

Comment: *"I created a blank project"* What kind of project / what project template? Second, [Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision/) shows support for .netstandard2.0 but NOT .netstandard2.1. This conflicts with the requirement of the above error message, which doesn't support 2.0. Your choices are to try to find an OLDER version that supports 2.0 (of the one that wants 2.1), OR to download sources of these nugets and add those projects to your solution. Build yourself.

Comment: Or go to github for ComputerVision, post an issue, try to get someone knowledgeable to rebuild that nuget for 2.1.

Comment: According to the error information you provided, you can see that the [System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/4.3.0#supportedframeworks-body-tab) package is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard, Version=v2.0), this package only supports netstandard1.0 and netstandard1.5